# Rearrangement of carbocation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

During rearrangement of carbocation, we have three choices: methyl shift, hydride shift and phenyl shift. If we have a situation where all the three are possible, then what will be the preference order?

Comment: Related: [Determination of products in reactions involving carbocation rearrangement?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7478/7951) and [Precedence of 1,2 carbocation rearrangement](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/25/7951)

Comment: You should look at stabilization in the transition state. Also, this seems like a homework question. Is it?

Comment: No, it's not. We don't get such questions in home work, it's something which was confusing me.

Comment: Voting to leave open per OP's comment. But, @user375072, the question *would* benefit from adding more detail about what you are and are not confident about as regards these different reaction pathways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases we study the stability of the carbocation resulting from the hydride/methyl/phenyl shift. That shift will be more favored whose resulting carbocation is the most stable.